# Can't submit Cordova app to the Play Store - (Your app currently targets API level 30 and must target at least API level 31)

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, html-framework-7

I'm attempting to submit a Cordova app (That's built using Framework7) to the Google Play Store, but I'm getting the message "Your app currently targets API level 30 and must target at least API level 31"

I've tried everything I can find to change the API level to 31. Uninstalling and installing SDKs, editing build.gradle files, changing what version of the android platform Cordova adds, but I get either nothing but errors or no closer to being able to upload the app.

And the thing is, is that I JUST published this app a few weeks ago, but apparently Google has changed their requirements since then. So I'm wondering if this is even possible at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Try add this code to your `config.xml` file inside `<platform name="android">` section:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="31" />
<preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="31" />
```

Comment: Setting `"cordova-android": "10.1.2",` in package.json and the above in config.xml worked for me with an Ionic AppFlow build .aab file upload to Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

To target level 31, you need to upgrade to cordova-android 11.0 and then set your target to 31.

See [this post](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2022/07/12/cordova-android-release-11.0.0.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and this is how I fix it on Monaca Platform. read this blog. after you set build environment for android setting. you need to add targetandroidSDK Version 31 by following these steps: go to Config -> App Setting for Android. That sit Good Luck

https://medium.com/the-web-tub/cordova-android-10-1-2-is-now-supported-b6c1329a784e

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).